# JavaScript express, node and CSVtoJSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, promise

I'm currently developing a 'Dupe Finder' web app for a co-worker. This is my first time using the 'csvtojson' package.

I'm reading from the file just fine on the server, but when I send a response back to the client (ideally containing a json object) I'm getting this very odd console log and I'm not sure if its correct:

[image: console.log(res.json())]

To get this response, I have a button on the home page, when clicked, the client makes an http request on the home directory of the server, called '/getnums'. The request reads from the CSV then should be returning and obj with its contents. It is *sort of* doing that, in the screenshot, if I click the tick next to promiseValue, it'll give me an array. But i'm not sure why its returning a Promise..anyway..

api.js:

```
var CSVDATA = () => {
fetch('/getnums')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.json())
    })
}

export default {
    CSVDATA,
}
```

'/getnums' goes to my router, which is simly router.get('/', mainController.getNums)

in the controller is where the reading begins:

```
const csv = require('csvtojson')

module.exports = {
getNums: (req, res, next) => {
    const csvFilePath = `${__dirname}/../../client/readFrom/main.csv`
    csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)
        .then(jsonObj => {
            return res.status(200).json(jsonObj)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            req.error = e
            next()
        })
    },
}
```

anyone have an idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simply how `.json()` works.

It returns promise so you need to handle it asynchronously

```
var CSVDATA = () => {
    fetch('/getnums')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
}

export default {
    CSVDATA,
}
```

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Comment: One last question, and I knew this would happen because I saw it in the Promise before.

Now that I have this object, I have a random key here:

https://prnt.sc/koabft

The 8008336917. Thats not a 'key' in my csv file anywhere or anything..Is there a way to 'strip' that key off?

Comment: I beleive this `key` is the first row of your csv. Take a look at header options of the library https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#header-row